# Google compute engine instance start/status/stop using api

Tags: php, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-api-php-client

I need to start the google cloud instance and stop if my process is over. 
So i tried api calls from https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get

Created API Key and oAuth client Id for the same and tried in postman application to test.

Used API Key in header `Authorization : Bearer <api_key>` and also in URL as `key=<api_key>`

But both methods are giving error `401 login required`.

Then i found API Explorer

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/

There also i got same error.

What is the mistake I'm doing. 
I need to implement instance start and stop through PHP code as it is background process.

PHP curl response

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to actually do this using env variable, as the google api php client library has a neat method.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('RandomNameYouNeedToInsert/0.1');
$client->addScope(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute'));
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$service = new Google_Service_Compute($client);

// TODO: Update placeholder values.
project = 'my-project';  
$zone = 'my-zone';  
$instance = 'my-instance';  

$response = $service->instances->start($project, $zone, $instance);
// TODO: Check if the response satisfies your request.
```

Comment: I used same code from google api doc but received response as 401 login required.

Comment: Try adding a scope - $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
Also you can add permissions for the service account to use compute engine via IAM
Also it would be nice if you edit your initial question with the response you are getting from the server.

Comment: will try adding scope and other stuff you said. Added response received from curl.

Comment: Yes. Got solution. I was trying with apiKey andOAuth only. I have not tried with service account option. @thefolenangel Thanks for your answer. Pls edit your answer with addScope line and highlight the punenv line. May be helpful for someone. Also add, Cloud compute requires service account authorization only.

Comment: @mockdev glad It helped, added the scope in the main answer.